# Editing Tumblr theme so external links open in new tab

Tags: html, tumblr

I'm trying to edit the Tumblr theme for my site at [www.dieinsel.tumblr.com](http://dieinsel.tumblr.com) so that links to external sites open in a new tab. I'm very new at all this, and have now ended up resorting to throwing `target="_blank"` everywhere I can find `a href` in the HTML. Which isn't working for me.

Any tips about where I can most strategically do this would be great. The main issue is the main image/link on the home page (which is in a 'post').

Comment: I can't find where to edit image links in posts in the tumblr theme html.

Comment: You added `target="_blank"` to the `<img>`-tag and not to the `<a>`-tag. It must be `<a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#"></a>`.

Comment: Thanks morkro. I can see that using Chrome's 'inspect element' but unfortunately I have no idea how to change that in the post itself. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place, but this is what I'm seeing:

Comment: <div class="post photo"><div class="wide">{LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}">{LinkCloseTag}</div><div class="narrow">{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}<div class="metadata">{block:ContentSource}<div class="date"><a href="{SourceURL}" target="_blank">Via {SourceTitle} </a></div>{/block:ContentSource}{block:IfShowPostTags}{block:HasTags}<div class="tags">{block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a>{/block:Tags}</div>{/block:HasTags}{/block:IfShowPostTags}

Comment: {block:IfShowPostNotes}{block:NoteCount}<div class="notes-count"><a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a></div>{/block:NoteCount}
{/block:IfShowPostNotes}

Comment: (sorry if that's too much info. I'm not sure what's relevant)

Comment: Okay for the future try to wrap all the code you want to post here on SO in ` (Grave accent). By this it will be displayed as code and is way more readable. Your problem is the `{LinkOpenTag}`, which seems to be a Tumblr variable and can't be edited in this snippet. I'm not familiar with Tumblr theming, but you need to add the `target="_blank"` to that variable. Somewhere those Tumblr variables get defined and there you can edit them. Here is a link to Tumblr's documentation: [http://buildthemes.tumblr.com/ch1/variables-blocks](http://buildthemes.tumblr.com/ch1/variables-blocks)

Comment: That explains why nothing's been working so far. I'll keep snooping. Thanks @morkro.

Comment: You have 'Open links in new window' enabled? http://i.imgur.com/fzH5EjN.png

Comment: Yes. And I've flicked it on and off and on again a few times just for good measure, but no joy.